# popViewController does not go back

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am making an app that is retrieving images from parse and showing it to a collection view. When the user taps on the images the image show in detail. I have a textfield that the user can change. When the user changes something they hit the save button and goes back to the collection view. The code that goes back to the collection view controller does not work.

```
  @IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Use the sent country object or create a new country PFObject
    if let saveInBackWithBlock = currentObject as PFObject? {
        updateObject = currentObject! as PFObject
    } else {
        updateObject = PFObject(className:"Tops")
    }

    // Update the object
    if let updateObject = updateObject {

        updateObject["imageText"] = topsLabel.text

        // Create a string of text that is used by search capabilites
        var searchText = (topsLabel.text)
        updateObject["searchText"] = searchText

        // Update the record ACL such that the new record is only visible to the current user
        updateObject.ACL = PFACL(user: PFUser.currentUser()!)

        // Save the data back to the server in a background task
        updateObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (success) {
                // The object has been saved.

            } else {
                // There was a problem, check error.description
            }
        }

        print("saved")

    }
   self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

        }
```

I don't know why it doesn't go back to the previous view controller.Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is your parent view embedded in a navigation controller? also - how has the view been presented?

From the post you just added - you cannot pop a modal VC - try dismissing the view controller instead.

Comment: Thank you. Yes the parent view is embed in a navigation view controller. The view is connected with a modal segue. I am using the following code to go to the detailview `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  objectToSend = tops[indexPath.row]
  performSegueWithIdentifier("showImage", sender: self)
 }`

Comment: As @Mike said since this is a modal presentation, you need to do `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)` (or true if you want it animated)

Comment: Thank you for your advise, was able to go back with dismissView

Comment: self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) in new Swift Version!

Answer (score -1):

Check if it's embed in Navigation Controller, try:

1. Click StroryBoard
2. Select first viewController
3. Click Editor -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller

Hope it helps.